# Cannot read property 'xPos' of undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a maze generator using JavaScript and [p5][1]. Everytime I run the code though it says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xPos' of undefined
    at draw (sketch.js:24)...

And also, it only shows my boring grid. I've been trying for so long to solve it and I can't find a solution. Here is my code:

Sketch.js:

```html
var cellSize = 32;
var cols = 20;
var rows = 20;
var grid = create2DArray(cols, rows);

var stack = [];
var currentCell = grid[0][0];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(cols * cellSize, rows * cellSize);

  generateCells();
}

function draw() {
  background(230);

  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      grid[x][y].draw();
    }
  }

  randomNeighbor(currentCell.xPos / cellSize, currentCell.y / cellSize);
}

function create2DArray(c, r) {
  var arr = new Array(c);

  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array(r);
  }

  return arr;
}
function generateCells() {
  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      var cell = new Cell(x * cellSize, y * cellSize);
      grid[x][y] = cell;
    }
  }

}
function randomCell() {
  var randomX = floor(random(0, cols));
  var randomY = floor(random(0, rows));
  var cell = grid[randomX][randomY];
  grid[randomX][randomY].visited = true;

  return cell;
}
function randomNeighbor(x, y) {
  if (getMoveable(x, y)) {
    append(stack, currentCell);

    var neighbors = [];
    if (x - 1 >= 0) append(neighbors, grid[x-1][y]);
    if (x + 1 <= cols) append(neighbors, grid[x+1][y]);
    if (y - 1 >= 0) append(neighbors, grid[x][y - 1]);
    if (y + 1 <= rows) append(neighbors, grid[x][y+1]);
    var rand = floor(random(0, neighbors.length));

    currentCell = neighbors[rand];

    removeWall(currentCell, stack[stack.length]);
  }
  else {
    currentCell = stack.pop();
  }
}
function getMoveable(x, y) {
  var moveable = false;

  var neighbors = [];
  if (x - 1 >= 0) append(neighbors, grid[x-1][y]);
  if (x + 1 <= cols) append(neighbors, grid[x+1][y]);
  if (y - 1 >= 0) append(neighbors, grid[x][y - 1]);
  if (y + 1 <= rows) append(neighbors, grid[x][y+1]);
  for (var i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
    if (neighbors[i].visited == true) {
      moveable = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return moveable;
}
function removeWall(a, b) {
  if (a.xPos - b.xPos == -cellSize) {
    grid[a.xPos / cellSize][a.yPos / cellSize].right = false;
  }
  else if (a.xPos - b.xPos == cellSize) {
    grid[b.xPos / cellSize][b.yPos / cellSize].right = false;
  }
  else if (a.yPos - b.yPos == -cellSize) {
    grid[a.xPos / cellSize][a.yPos / cellSize].bottom = false;
  }
  else if (a.yPos - b.yPos == cellSize) {
    grid[b.xPos / cellSize][b.yPos / cellSize].bottom = false;
  }
}
```

Cell.js:

```html
function Cell(xx, yy) {
  this.xPos = xx;
  this.yPos = yy;
  this.visited = false;

  this.right = true;
  this.bottom = true;

  this.draw = function() {
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(1);

    if (this.right) {
      line(this.xPos + cellSize, this.yPos, this.xPos + cellSize, this.yPos + cellSize);
    }
    if (this.bottom) {
      line(this.xPos, this.yPos + cellSize, this.xPos + cellSize, this.yPos + cellSize);
    }
  }
}
```

index.html (The thing I open in my browser):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cell.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `var currentCell = grid[0][0];`, the `grid` array is empty, so `currentCell` becomes `undefined`. You should update `currentCell` as soon as you fill the `grid` with cells:

```
function generateCells() {
  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      var cell = new Cell(x * cellSize, y * cellSize);
      grid[x][y] = cell;
    }
  }
  currentCell = grid[0][0];
}
```

Comment: That fixed that error, but now there is a new one: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visited' of undefined
    at getMoveable (sketch.js:81)

Comment: @NumNumDude Before appending an element to the `neighbors` array, you have to check if it exists.

Comment: It should exist if the if statement before it is true.